# How to select data based on a MAX(key) without grouping

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm not sure that the title is very descriptive, but here's the question...

Is there a way to select a data column based on a Max key value, joined across multiple tables.  Please consider:

```
Table A
-------
PK1
PK2
PK3
PK4
dataColumn
... data

Table B
-------
PK1
PK2
PK3
... data

Table C
-------
PK1
PK2
PK3
PK4
... data

SELECT A.dataColumn, A.PK1, A.PK2, MAX(A.PK3), A.PK4
FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.PK1 = b.PK1 AND a.PK2 = b.PK2 AND a.PK3 = b.PK3
         INNER JOIN C c ON a.PK1 = c.PK1 AND a.PK2 = c.PK2 AND a.PK3 = c.PK3 AND a.PK4 = c.PK4
GROUP BY A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK4 -- I do not want to add in A.dataColumn
```

The problem is in order to get MAX(A.PK3), i have to also group by the data, which I do not want.  Having, A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK4, and MAX(A.PK3) uniquely defines the row I want.  By adding in the group by, I will get the MAX(A.PK3) for each A.dataColumn and that is not what I want.  Essentially, A.PK3 is a datetime field; I want the data for the latest time based on the other keys.  The other keys uniquely identify some equipment, the time is the time of the error, and then the data is the error information (very simplified).  I want the latest error information for the specified PK1, PK2, and PK4.

Presently, we split into two, nearly identical queries and join them as:

```
SELECT j.PK1, j.PK2, j.PK3, j.PK4, k.dataColumn
FROM A a 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT A.PK1, A.PK2, MAX(A.PK3), A.PK4 -- no data column selected
  FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.PK1 = b.PK1 AND a.PK2 = b.PK2 AND a.PK3 = b.PK3
           INNER JOIN C c ON a.PK1 = c.PK1 AND a.PK2 = c.PK2 AND a.PK3 = c.PK3 AND a.PK4 = c.PK4
  GROUP BY A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK4
) j
ON a.PK1 = j.PK1 AND a.PK2 = j.PK2 AND a.PK3 = j.PK3 AND a.PK4 = j.PK4
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT A.dataColumn, A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK3, A.PK4 -- data column, but no MAX
  FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.PK1 = b.PK1 AND a.PK2 = b.PK2 AND a.PK3 = b.PK3
           INNER JOIN C c ON a.PK1 = c.PK1 AND a.PK2 = c.PK2 AND a.PK3 = c.PK3 AND a.PK4 = c.PK4
) k
ON j.PK1 = k.PK1 AND j.PK2 = k.PK2 AND j.PK3 = k.PK3 AND j.PK4 = k.PK4
```

So, as you can see, the first INNER JOIN gets the PKs, but not the data, then the second join gets the data from the PKs in the first inner join.  This seems HORRIBLE!  This example is overly simplified, but in our case, the tables we are joining contain millions of records and the operation is nearly identical in each JOIN.

Any help removing one of the inner joins would be awesome and appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, in SQL 2005 and up, is to use one of the "ranking" functions, like so:

```
SELECT SubQuery.dataColumn, SubQuery.PK1, SubQuery.PK2, SubQuery.A.PK3, SubQuery.PK4
FROM (SELECT A.dataColumn, A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK3, A.PK4
       ,row_number() over (partition by A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK4 order by A.PK3 desc) Ranking
      FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.PK1 = b.PK1 AND a.PK2 = b.PK2 AND a.PK3 = b.PK3
               INNER JOIN C c ON a.PK1 = c.PK1 AND a.PK2 = c.PK2 AND a.PK3 = c.PK3 AND a.PK4 = c.PK4
      GROUP BY A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK4) SubQuery
 WHERE SubQuery.Ranking = 1
```

Best explained in detail in [books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx). Caveats: I cannot test the above code, there may be typos or minor bugs. Also, while logically sound, it may perform poorly, so testing for adequate performance is required.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll test this out and post how this performs compared to splitting the query as indicated.